# gfortran generate dependencies on module files

Tags: makefile, fortran, dependencies, gfortran

I want to use gfortran to generate suitable rules for a Makefile, with sources that use modules.

E.g., if in `src1.f90`

```
program prog
  use module1
  ...
end program
```

and in `mod_mymods.f90`

```
module module1
 ...
end module module1
```

I want to generate a line like

```
src1.f90: mod_mymods.f90
```

**Is that possible?**

**Does [this](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/fluidity/+spec/auto-generated-module-dependencies) suggest that gfortran>=4.5 can do that?**

Note that the only way to find such dependencies is by parsing all f90 files until there is a match between `use module1` and `module module1`.
Or, one can maintain an index of source files <-> modules, and have `make` keep it up to date.

Alternatives found are:

https://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/homes/hcp/fmkmf

https://www.reddit.com/r/fortran/comments/8n3tr5/makefiles_with_modules_dependency_hierarchies_in/

https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-makedepf90/

https://simplyfortran.com/ (but it is a whole IDE)

http://lagrange.mechse.illinois.edu/f90_mod_deps/

https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-gen-dep#70055AC3-6C05-42BB-8ED5-6EBB0E7F5C71

Comment: If you want to go this way, it is your choice and the answers should stay on-topic, but I really have to note that modern build system don't need any dependency lists and just work automatically (cmake, scons, waf, FoBiS,...).

Comment: The USE statement is the dependency, and the makefile just aborts when the error that .mod is not found returns from the compiler.

Comment: @VladimirF - Thanks. Would you know about the two questions posted?

Comment: No, I hate Makefiles after spending way too much time trying making them work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems generating such dependency is not possible directly with `gfortran`.

Use of `cmake` (e.g.) seems to automatically account for that, even if I did not check the resulting makefile, and I wouldn't know how does `cmake` parse the contents of `src1.f90` and `mod_mymods.f90` to be able to tell the dependency.